# Expectation value and Dispersion of an Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, eigenvalue, dispersion

Suppose we have an operator $Q$ with eigenvalue $q$. Expectation value is $\langle Q \rangle$ and dispersion $D(Q) = \sqrt{\langle \left( Q - \langle Q \rangle \right)^2  \rangle} $. I want to find values for the expectation value and dispersion.

**Attempt**

Expectation value is simply the average value of the observable associated with $Q$ right? Dispersion is the variance of the observable associated with $Q$ right?

$$ \langle Q \rangle = \langle \psi | Q |\psi \rangle = q \langle \psi|\psi \rangle = q  $$

$$ D(Q) =  \sqrt{\langle \left( Q - \langle Q \rangle \right)^2  \rangle} = \sqrt{ \langle Q^2 -2Q \langle Q\rangle + \langle Q \rangle^2         \rangle }  = \sqrt{ \langle Q^2 - 2Qq + q^2   \rangle }  $$

Now $\langle Q^2 \rangle  = q^2 $ by applying $Q$ twice.

Does this mean that $$D(Q) = 0 $$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There's an even easier notation for dispersion, or standard deviation which is

$$D(Q) = \sqrt{ \langle Q^2\rangle - \langle Q\rangle^2 }$$

Both those terms are the same. So $D(Q)$ is zero.

Comment: No idea how to use the math notation on here yet.

Comment: Then what's the dispersion $D(x)$ of this wavefunction? $\left( \frac{2}{\pi a^2} \right)^{\frac{1}{4}} exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{a^2} + ikx \right)$ ? Surely it can't be zero.

Comment: Is the above equation an eigenstate of x?

Comment: yes, it's an eigenstate of x

Comment: If you do it out (I used integral notation in the position basis) it's a lot easier. In your question above, you made it seem as if Q did not depend on q.

Comment: Ok I get it. So primarily I have to find $\langle x \rangle^2$ and $\langle x^2 \rangle$

Comment: @jhobbie: You can use `$ $` to start MathJax for the "math notation" here. Some more information on MathJax can be found [at this help center topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @user44840 yep!